# How can I create pug file with hashed resource name on it using Webpack 2.0?

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, pug

My directory structure is as follows.

```
/public
  (git-ignored files)
/src
  index.js
/views
  index.pug

server.js
webpack.config.js
```

#### index.pug

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/public/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    script.
      var LANGUAGES = '#{languages}';
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="body"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The key here is that `#{languages}` is directly used by `server.js`.

#### server.js

```
...

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', './views');

app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  const cookieLanguage = req.cookies[key];
  const languages = cookieLanguage
    ? cookieLanguage
    : req.headers['accept-language'];

  res.render('index', { languages });
});

...
```

Which means that `index.pug` should be `.pug`, not `.html`, and in `./views` directory to be directly used by `server.js`. (`languages` value can be changed based on request header value, as you see above.) AFAIK, `pug-html-loader` and `pug-loader` convert `.pug` files into static `.html` file(s).

So far I've been using static `style.css` and `bundle.js` filenames and it's working without any problem but now I want my `index.pug` file to have hashed source filename. Something like

#### index.pug (desired)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="/public/main.cdd8fd4b583e80bf95fc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    script.
      var LANGUAGES = '#{languages}';
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="body"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/main.cdd8fd4b583e80bf95fc.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can already create those hashed filename through `webpack.config.js`.

#### webpack.config.js

```
...

(somewhere)

new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].[hash].css'
})

...

(somewhere)

output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
  filename: '[name].[hash].js',
  publicPath: '/public/'
},

...
```

I saw `html-webpack-plugin` exactly doing this with `.html` extension, but I can't find the example of doing it with `.pug` output. Any suggestion or walkaround?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: @EdHinchliffe It's kind of a workaround. I'll post my solution if you still seek one.

Answer (score 3):

I recently wrote a webpack plugin that I think solves your problem. It creates a `.pug` file with a list of script tags, including hashed bundle names.

Just include it in your `index.pug` with:

`include your-path/dist/pug-manifest.pug`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-pug-manifest-plugin

Comment: Yeah the doc looks to be the one. But I can't really test the plugin now because I'm out of the project the I had worked on. Great work!

Comment: it puts all script tags in one file? how do you include script tags you need for certain file?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It doesn't currently support that, but that's a great feature idea!